# Microsoft SQL Server : CONCAT() with INSERT

Tags: sql-server

I am currently attempting to combine 2 columns into 1 using `CONCAT()`.

I have

```
SELECT
    ApplicationTitle,
    ApplicationVersion,
    CONCAT(ApplicationTitle,'  ',' - ','  ',ApplicationVersion) as ApplicationName
FROM 
    <DataBaseName>
    -- Hid DataBase name due to privacy concerns.
```

Now this works and gives me the result I would like, but I need to not just see the result but actually insert it into the table as a new column with those values so I can delete `ApplicationTitle` and `ApplicationVersion`. Reasoning is when exporting the information (I do not have control over how the information gets exported out), it separates `ApplicationTitle` from `ApplicationVersion` (to clarify, they are application names and application versions, but I need it into 1 column with a - divider, e.g. ApplicationTitle = SQL, ApplicationVersion = 4.0, I want ApplicationName = SQL - 4.0). I've looked online but could not find something similar that worked for my current situation due to needing to delete `ApplicationTitle` and `ApplicationVersion` after `ApplicationName` has been populated.

What is the best way to go about doing this. My thought was `INSERT INTO` command with `CONCAT` but that doesn't seem to work for me (I'm sure I'm missing something).

Comment: Is the new column in the same table?

Comment: 3 steps: add column, populate  new column, remove old columns.  Note it makes more sense to keep the data separated (IMO). 1) `alter table add column ApplicationName varchar(100);` 2) `Update table set ApplicationName = CONCAT(ApplicationTitle,'  ',' - ','  ',ApplicationVersion);` 3) `alter table drop column applicationTitle, applicationVersion;`

Comment: Thanks, this worked

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You have a table named `TableName` and `TableName` has one column name `ColumnName`, then you can insert row at `TableName` by following query:

```
INSERT INTO TableName
 (ColumnName)
SELECT 
  CONCAT(ApplicationTitle, '  ', ' - ', '  ', ApplicationVersion)
FROM YourTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new table and insert the records how you like, but if you try to run this again with the same table name it will give an error like "table already exists":

```
SELECT
    ApplicationTitle,
    ApplicationVersion,
    ApplicationName = CONCAT(ApplicationTitle,'  ',' - ','  ',ApplicationVersion)
INTO <NewTableName>
FROM <DataBaseName>
```